# Decode statement: strange behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have some issues with the following statement:

```
SELECT  1
FROM   dual
WHERE  DECODE(1,
          0,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl),
          1) > 0
```

If 'tbl' is empty, execution of this query somehow returns nothing.

On the other hand, execution of query:

```
SELECT  1
FROM   dual
WHERE  DECODE(1,
          0,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl),
          1) = 1
```

returns 1.

Furthermore, this:

```
SELECT  1
FROM   dual
WHERE  DECODE(1,
          0,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl),
          1) = 0
```

also returns 1. What am I missing?

**EDIT 1** sqlplus listing

```
SQL> select count(*) from ids;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     0

SQL> SELECT  1
  2  FROM   dual
  3  WHERE  DECODE(1,
  4            0,
  5            (SELECT COUNT(*) from ids),
  6            1) > 0;

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT  1
  2  FROM   dual
  3  WHERE  DECODE(1,
  4            0,
  5            (SELECT COUNT(*) from ids),
  6            1) =1;

         1
----------
         1

SQL> SELECT  1
  2  FROM   dual
  3  WHERE  DECODE(1,
  4            0,
  5            (SELECT COUNT(*) from ids),
  6            1) =0;

         1
----------
         1
```

Comment: Which version are you seeing that behaviour in? I get 1, 1, and no rows respectively, regardless of how many rows are in `tbl`, in 11.2.0.3.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. My Oracle version is 11.2.0.4

Comment: Does `SELECT DECODE(1, 0, (SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl), 1) FROM DUAL` give different results depending on the number of rows in `tbl`? It should obviously always return 1, so any other behaviour looks like a bug. (Unless you've got the query and result order mixed up...)

Comment: `SELECT DECODE(1, 0, (SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl), 1) FROM DUAL` is always gives me 1. But when I use DECODE in WHERE clause some strange things are happening.

Comment: You're 100% sure you get no rows with `> 0` and one row with `= 0`, not the other way around? Just feel the need to double-check.

Comment: I double-checked, but the problem is still there. I've added sqlplus output in the original post

Comment: Thanks, sorry if that seemed like I was being a pain, but it's been know for crucial mistakes to appear when questions are entered. Certainly looks like a bug then as it doesn't do that in 11.2.0.3 (or 10.2.0.5 or 9.2.0.7). Might be worth raising a service request; I can't see anything like this in My Oracle Support.

Comment: I didn't have an opportunity to reproduce the issue in another oracle versions, so thank you very much for your help. I think I'll take your advice and raise a service request. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Get the decode out of the where cause by nesting it in a select.  It's not going to be efficient, but it should work.  What are you really trying to do here?  Can you give an example using something other than numbers :).

SELECT  1
FROM   dual
WHERE  (select DECODE(1,
                      0,
                      (SELECT COUNT(*) from ids),
                      1)
        from dual) =0;

Comment: That doesn't address why the behaviour appears tone wrong. This may work around the problem (don't have 11.2.0.4 to test) but doesn't really answer the question; it should work anyway, and does in earlier releases. I *suspect* the OP has reduced this to the simplest example they can, having seen the issue in more complicated code.

Comment: Yes, I've already replaced this unreliable statement with similar construction and my script works just fine now. But there's no guarantee that someone else won't face this problem in future. It obviously just should work. Since I have no Oracle Support ID myself I've informed my employer and I believe they will raise a support request.
PS. I checked - decode wrapped in select works correctly in 11.2.0.4
Excuse my English:)